# Is there a number or ID that I can give to people that want to video call me with Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts, chat, user-accounts

I want to have people be able to call my on Google Hangouts.   They can search by name to find me, but there are several people and profiles with my name and they don't always get the right one.

Is there a number or ID that I can give to people to reach me over Google Hangouts?

<sub>I know for Skype I can give out my Skype ID, but I haven't found the equivalent for Google Hangouts.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think there used to be a way to embed a link in a web page for this, but I'm having trouble finding it now.

You can also just begin a Hangout and you'll get a URL that you can share with anyone who you'd like to join that Hangout.

Comment: I think you are referring to the [Hangouts button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button).  It looks like you can set it to suggest people to put on the call:   "The list is only a suggestion to the user that starts the Hangout. Before the Hangout begins, that user will be able to skip the invite or change the list of people."   So it sounds like the UI is a bit klunky for the purposes of "click to call me".

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I can send people a link to my Google+ profile page which has an icon to start a hangout with me.

[image: hangout icon on Google+ profile page]

This isn't an ideal solution.

1. The hangout icon is not prominent on the profile page.  Some people can't find it.
2. You can't search for a Google Plus URL to add a person to a hangout, so there is not way to use the profile URL from within the application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Advice [Add people by sharing a link](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3110347) includes:

> 1. In the video call window, click the screen.
> 2. At the top, click Add people [image: icon] Copy link to share [image: Link].
> 3. To invite people to the call, click the link to copy it. Then, paste the link into emails, chats, or somewhere else. To join a call,
>      users will need to sign in. Anyone with the link will be able to join
>      the call.

but I regret I do *not* know whether or not relevant.

Comment: I guess that works if you are willing leave a call open for the person.   It wouldn't work for a "call me tomorrow" link though.